# Filtro por data em uma tabela com javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, banco-de-dados, filtro

Aviso agora de início que para a minha pergunta, irei utilizar apenas dados focados para o problema, sem necessitar colocar todos os campos de uma tabela e todo o corpo HTML. Demorei bastante para elaborar esta pergunta, mas tenho certeza que ficou bem explicado.

Tenho a tabela **cde_venda_detalhe** com todas as vendas realizadas da empresa. Nesta tabela tem a coluna **criadoem**, que indica a data da realização da venda.

Exemplo:

```php
| id | preco  | criadoem                  |
| 1  | 199.99 | S:27. 29/06/2020 às 11:40 |
| 2  | 151.00 | S:27. 02/07/2020 às 13:20 |
| 3  | 19.99  | S:27. 05/07/2020 às 18:00 |
| 4  | 120.00 | S:28. 06/07/2020 às 09:00 |
| 5  | 12.50  | S:28. 06/07/2020 às 10:10 |
```

A coluna é do tipo *varchar*, tendo a semana, dia, mês, ano e hora da realização da venda:  `date('\S:W\. d/m/Y \à\s H:i')`

Utilizo 5 filtros diferentes na tabela do HTML:

- Total
- Diária
- Semanal
- Mensal
- Anual

Este é meu código atual (Funcionando):

```php
$dia = date('d/m/Y');
$semana = date('\S:W\.');
$mes = date('m/Y');
$ano = date('Y');

$filtro = 0;

if ($filtro == 0) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cde_venda_detalhe";
} else if ($filtro == 1) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cde_venda_detalhe WHERE criadoem LIKE '%$dia%'";
} else if ($filtro == 2) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cde_venda_detalhe WHERE criadoem LIKE '%$semana%' AND criadoem LIKE '%$ano%'";
} else if ($filtro == 3) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cde_venda_detalhe WHERE criadoem LIKE '%$mes%'";
} else if ($filtro == 4) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cde_venda_detalhe WHERE criadoem LIKE '%$ano%'";
}

$data = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);
if ($data['total'] == 'Total') {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cde_venda_detalhe";
}
if ($data['diaria'] == 'Diaria') {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cde_venda_detalhe WHERE criadoem LIKE '%$dia%'";
}
if ($data['semanal'] == 'Semanal') {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cde_venda_detalhe WHERE criadoem LIKE '%$semana%'";
}
if ($data['mensal'] == 'Mensal') {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cde_venda_detalhe WHERE criadoem LIKE '%$mes%'";
}
if ($data['anual'] == 'Anual') {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cde_venda_detalhe WHERE criadoem LIKE '%$ano%'";
}
```

```php
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <button name="total" value="Total" type="submit"> Total</button>
     <button name="diaria" value="Diaria" type="submit"> Diária</button>
     <button name="semanal" value="Semanal" type="submit"> Semanal</button>
     <button name="mensal" value="Mensal" type="submit"> Mensal</button>
     <button name="anual" value="Anual" type="submit"> Anual</button>
</form>

<table>
      <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Id da Venda</th>
               <th>Preço da Venda</th>
               <th>Data da Venda</th>
            </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <?php foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) { ?>
            <tr>
               <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['preco']; ?></td>
               <!--Por questão de estética, não exibo a semana na tabela-->
               <td><?php echo substr($row['criadoem'], 5); ?></td>
            </tr>
      <?php } ?>   
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Porém, gostaria desse filtro sem precisar sempre enviar um formulário, ou seja, em javascript, porém javascript não é meu forte.

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Cara, ficou difícil de entender o contexto e como está sendo realizada essa consulta.
Porque você está realizando chamadas ao banco de dados dessa forma? porque não utilizar um ORM e uma API para lidar com esses dados? Outro ponto é, porque na estrutura do seu banco uma coluna de data está no formato string?

Comment: Inicialmente essa data era só para informação, porém depois precisei utilizar ela para consultas, no caso esta pergunta acima. Apesar de estar funcionando, sei que não é a maneira mais correta, ainda preciso aprender mais, aliás não tenho faculdade, apenas um Curso Técnico de Informática que foi realizado junto ao ensino médio, e digamos que eles não ligavam muito para o desenvolvimento e sim para o hardware e redes. Enfim, os que tinham interesse em programação precisaram se esforçar para aprender essa parte, que é minha favorita

Comment: Eu ainda coloquei a data no formato correto, mas precisei desta parte da semana, como não consegui fazer identificar a semana através da data, e como não tem como inserir o número da semana da data, tinha duas opções: ou adicionava uma coluna só para a semana da venda, ou deixaria ela tipo string, contendo a semana (que é esta de agora). Mas não se preocupe, a única tabela que contém data que está como string é esta.

Comment: Legal cara, bom ver que está correndo atrás. Existe um problema muito grave no que você está fazendo: a consulta está no Javascript. Sua consulta deve estar na parte do servidor, porque o que está no cliente, o usuário pode modificar. Permitindo assim uma injeção de SQL na sua base de dados. Recomendo você reformular este código para que em vez de 5 botões, você tenha uma DropDown com as opções, e o servidor trate conforme o valor a construção da consulta

Answer (score 1):

1 - Você vai ter que carregar todos os filtros em campos div ocultos e exibi-los conforme a seleção. O único método pelo lado do cliente é esse. pois qualquer outro você teria que informar dados de conexão a sua base de dados de forma insegura. Isso se existir o método. Mesmo o Node.js é uma linguagem server-side e precisaria ser carregado com form toda vez que fosse solicitado.
Talvez ajude informar que não é preciso recarregar a página inteira para submeter um form. basta usar AJAX e inserir apenas o conteúdo retornado em sua página.

2 - date('w',$time)